# Glusterfs installation done but unable to start services on second node

Tags: linux, glusterfs

I am installing `glusterfs` filesystem on ubuntu and linux 6, trying to connect these two servers as peer in volume.

I successfully installed it on both servers, but due to some replication issues I stopped `glusterfs` service on the linux 6 server. After which I am unable to start the service on same server.

Digging through the logs I found the following errors.

> glusterfs  tail -f cli.log [2015-06-22 16:36:13.342468] W
>   [socket.c:642:__socket_rwv] 0-glusterfs: readv on
>   /var/run/glusterd.socket failed (Invalid argument) [2015-06-22
>   16:36:13.342496] I [socket.c:2409:socket_event_handler] 0-transport:
>   disconnecting now [2015-06-22 16:36:15.490601] W
>   [cli-rl.c:106:cli_rl_process_line] 0-glusterfs: failed to process line
>   [2015-06-22 16:36:16.344012] W [socket.c:642:__socket_rwv]
>   0-glusterfs: readv on /var/run/glusterd.socket failed (Invalid
>   argument) [2015-06-22 16:36:16.344067] I
>   [socket.c:2409:socket_event_handler] 0-transport: disconnecting now
>   [2015-06-22 16:36:19.346585] W [socket.c:642:__socket_rwv]
>   0-glusterfs: readv on /var/run/glusterd.socket failed (Invalid
>   argument) [2015-06-22 16:36:19.346641] I
>   [socket.c:2409:socket_event_handler] 0-transport: disconnecting now
>   [2015-06-22 16:36:20.545822] W [cli-rl.c:106:cli_rl_process_line]
>   0-glusterfs: failed to process line [2015-06-22 16:36:22.346947] W
>   [socket.c:642:__socket_rwv] 0-glusterfs: readv on
>   /var/run/glusterd.socket failed (Invalid argument) [2015-06-22
>   16:36:22.347001] I [socket.c:2409:socket_event_handler] 0-transport:
>   disconnecting now

No `glusterfs` process is running on same server.

Thanks in advance.